# Copying files from the terminal with confirmation message before copying each file

Tags: command-line, copy

I want to copy files from one folder to another, but I want to make the terminal ask for confirmation of copying files before copying each file. Is there any way?

I know there is `cp -i` but that only asks before overwriting.

Comment: Can you explain the use case  a bit? What's the point of asking for confirmation for every file? If you don't want to copy something, then don't copy it. In what context would a confirmation be useful?

Answer (score 5):

You could implement something with the `find` command's `-ok` predicate:

> ```
>    -ok command ;
>           Like  -exec but ask the user first.  If the user agrees, run the
>           command.  Otherwise just return false.  If the command  is  run,
>           its standard input is redirected from /dev/null.
> ```

So for example

```
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -name '*.jpg' -ok cp -t ../newdir {} \;
< cp ... ./aaa.jpg > ? y
< cp ... ./aaa-small.jpg > ? n
< cp ... ./bbb.jpg > ? n
< cp ... ./ccc-small.jpg > ? y
< cp ... ./ccc.jpg > ? y
< cp ... ./bbb-small.jpg > ? n

$ ls ../newdir
aaa.jpg  ccc.jpg  ccc-small.jpg
```

Comment: Thanks for 'find -ok command' :-)